# Handling specific Entity Framework exceptions - standards/guidelines?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, exception, entity-framework-5

**When querying from the database using Entity Framework, what exceptions should one catch and what should be done about them?**

Generally I use `catch(Exception)` because I have no specific action or feedback for every possible type of error, but I am constantly reminded that this is a terrible idea and that specific exceptions should be caught and handled!  Example:

```
try
{
    using(MyEntities context = new MyEntities())
    {
        context.Companies.Attach(company);
        ActiveEmployees = company.Employees.Where(x => x.IsActive).ToList();
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Feedback(FeedbackType.ApplicationError); // User feedback
    Logger.Log(ex);  // Log the exception
}
```

What are the standards/guidelines for handling EF exceptions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many exceptions should not be caught but prevented. I mean that exceptions like violating FK constraints or other database constraints, attaching entities that already are attached, lazy loading when the context is disposed, unsupported LINQ statements, etc. **should bubble up** in unit tests/integration tests. That's why I would not use such a general try-catch that deep in your code (it looks like some kind of repository or service method) but higher up, e.g. in a UI or view model. They *should* make your tests crash.

There's one exception I can think of that you may want to catch and handle close to the data access code and that's the **optimistic concurrency** exception. This is because concurrency conflicts can not be fully prevented in code (the timing always leaves gaps) and you have to rely on the database to throw exceptions when they occur. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592904.aspx) for some patterns how to deal with optimistic concurrency.

Answer (score 1):

There's a gazillion exceptions that might be thrown by those few statements.
You might not have a network connection to the database.
The company you attach might be attached to another context.
Employees might not be virtual or not loaded in the first place and hence null.
You'll have to check the documentation for each method and figure out what you might have to catch.

But my two cents are that you've already caught them all, and you do the only thing you can.
You log them and ask the user what he/she did. (And possibly send yourself an e-mail?)

After doing this for a while, you'll have a log showing which exceptions actually do occur, and you can decide what to do with them. But mostly the user is only interested in knowing that the site is "down" and will be back up in *n*.